# Partition mount error on boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I wanted to mount a partition automatically on boot, so I used storage device manager, as recommended on ubuntu help. The problem is I named it with my name instead of leaving it default. So, instead of monuting it to media/sda3, it tries to mount to media/Fabio (which is my name). The problem is it can't mount and always says "error mounting media/Fabio. Press S to skip or M to manually mount it"

here is an image of my fstab file on /lib/init/fstab

[image]

I searched for similar topics but none of them worked or were exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This fstab doesn't even have the device you're talking about in it. Can you copy `/etc/fstab` into your question? That should have the device listed.

Comment: Generally, I think it is better not to touch /lib/init/fstab unless you know what you're doing and only ever modify /etc/fstab. The former is used in the early boot process so many things are not yet available/mounted/loaded.

Comment: this is what etc/fstab looks like
http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/9065/screenshot2jz.png

I had posted lib/init/fstab. Sorry. If I delete the line /dev/sda3                                  /media/Fabio Esteves  ntfs  nls=iso8859-1,users,umask=000,user  0  0 which contains the partition I do not want to try to mount, will it mount only the other one? thank you

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by the user by removing the bad partition line in `/etc/fstab`.